# Moving from a webbrowser control to a WebClient

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, webclient

I'm looking to move from using a webbrowser control to direct interaction with the internet though WebClient. My first (and most important) question is whether I can programatically log into a webpage, enter data into inputs and click buttons on the webpage all with WebClient. For example I use the following code to enter data into a webpage using a webbrowser control (in a non UI thread):

```
 If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    Dim element As HtmlElement = webbrow.Document.GetElementById("SOMEELEMID")
                    If element IsNot Nothing Then
                        element.InnerText = TextBox4.Text
                    End If
                End Sub
)
```

And likewise I use this code to click buttons in the webbrowser control:

```
                If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    Dim element As HtmlElement = webbrow.Document.GetElementById("target")
                    If element IsNot Nothing Then
                        element.InvokeMember("Click")
                    End If
                End Sub
)
```

Are the above things possible (even though the code will be different) with a WebClient? If so any advice would be great!

Comment: You have deleted your original question too fast, you should have edited it instead. My answer actually had some useful information.

Comment: Did they? Sorry I thought you just liked to the MSDN article on webclient. Would you mind posting your answer again?

Comment: I also linked the info on HTML Agility Pack and PhantomJS.  Anyway, you won't be able to "click" the button with `WebClient` to submit the form, you'll have to manually compose the body of HTTP POST request.

Comment: OK. So how would I go about composing the HTTP POST request? Thanks